# Class with an Observable Object has been used by is not initializing

Tags: swift, xcode

I've added an Observable Object to my class DetailViewModel, but I am getting an error "Class 'DetailViewModel' has no initializers". Can anyone explain why?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@MainActor
 class DetailViewModel: ObservableObject{
    
    @Published   var strMeal: String = ""
    @Published   var strInstructions: String
    @Published   var strIngredient: String
    @Published   var strMeasure: String
    @Published   var strMealThumb:URL?
    
    
     private func loadMealDetails(idMeal: String) async {
         do {
             let mealDetailResponse = try await  WebServiceRequest().loadData(url: Constants.Urls.getMealByIdUrl(strMeal)) { data in
              return try?   JSONDecoder().decode(MealDetailModel.self, from:data )
             }


         } catch {
               print(error)
         }
     }
```

Comment: Hi -- did my answer address your question? If it was correct, you can mark it as such with the green checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: yes, but it was actually an xcode issue, I had to delete my file and paste everything again and the  ObservableObject worked. But the issue was my coco touch file that was not linked to my main.storyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined some properties (`strInstructions`, `strIngredient`, and `strMeasure`) that don't have initial values specified. Unlike `struct`s, which get synthesized initializers (eg the compiler makes a initializer for us), with a `class`, we have to create an initializer ourselves (or give all of the properties default values).

With default values, it may look like:

```
@MainActor
class DetailViewModel: ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var strMeal: String = ""
    @Published var strInstructions: String = ""
    @Published var strIngredient: String = ""
    @Published var strMeasure: String = ""
    @Published var strMealThumb:URL?
    
}
```

Or, with an initializer, it could be something like:

```
@MainActor
class DetailViewModel: ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var strMeal: String = ""
    @Published var strInstructions: String
    @Published var strIngredient: String
    @Published var strMeasure: String
    @Published var strMealThumb:URL?
    
    init(strInstructions: String, strIngredient: String, strMeasure: String) {
        self.strInstructions = strInstructions
        self.strIngredient = strIngredient
        self.strMeasure = strMeasure
    }
}
```

You may also want to accept values for `strMeal` and `strMealThumb` in your initializer -- it's up to you.